# Как защитить api от доступа неофициальных клиентов?

Tags: php, objective-c, ios, laravel

Есть приложение на ios (objective-c) и серверная часть на laravel 5 (php).
Хочу чтобы доступ к api был только у официального клиента. 
Насколько я понял нужно подписывать запрос на клиенте и проверять его на сервере.
Буду благодарен за любые ссылки-туториалы по этой теме.

Comment: Если правильно понял, то можно попробовать привязать к device id. Правда в таком случае, сперва его нужно будет внести в базу. И при коннекте, передавать этот device id. При необходимости, можно и зашифровать чем-нибудь.

Answer (score 2):

Есть одна фундаментальная проблема, вся подпись будет на клиенте, а клиент всегда можно реверс-инженерить, так что сделать доступ только официальному клиенту не получится. 
Однако, что получится, так это *усложнить* процесс получения доступа.

Например: Встроить в приложение публичный ключ и шифровать все данные с помощью него и на сервере с помощью приватного ключа расшифровывать. 
Это поможет защититься от простого сниффинга запросов на сервер.

Что-бы усложнить получение публичного ключа, можно попытаться применить обфускацию, например с помощью, [cocoapods-keys](https://github.com/orta/cocoapods-keys) или подобных инструметнов.

Тем не менее, обфуцированные ключи тоже достаточно просто достать, нужно всего-лишь использовать дебаггер.

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать так, чтобы пользователь авторизовался в вашем api, получив токен авторизации (Guid), который живет, например день.
И потом в каждом запросе к какой либо функции, передавал вам токен авторизации.
Например:
https://tech.yandex.ru/direct/doc/dg-v4/examples/auth-token-sample-docpage/

Comment: вы не поняли вопрос. мы нужно чтобы доступ к api имел только официальный клиент. по вашей же схеме я могу после авторизации перехватить адрес с токеном через снифер